# Pug в HTML не компилируется GULP

Tags: gulp

почему компиляция pug в html не проходит?
Мой gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    pug = require('pug'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch')
gulp.task('project:watch', function()
{
    watch('./dev/views/*.html', function()
    {
        gulp.src('./dev/views/*.pug')
            .pipe(pug.renderFile('./dev/views/*.pug', {
                name: 'test'
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('prod'))
    })
    watch('./dev/styles/*.scss', function()
    {
        gulp.src('./dev/styles/*.scss')
            .pipe(
                plumber(function(error)
                {
                    this.emit('end')
                })
            )
            .pipe(sass())
            .pipe(autoprefixer())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('prod/css'))
    })
    watch('./dev/scripts/*.js', function()
    {
        gulp.src('./dev/scripts/*.js')
            .pipe(gulp.dest('prod/js'))
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы компилировать `pug` с помощью `gulp` нужен не `pug`, а `gulp-pug` — https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-pug.